# Azure Web App Deploy Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSitePublishingCredentialsEnabled' of undefined

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, devops, azure-webapps

[image]I received an error of

"2023-04-25T01:04:23.0050662Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSitePublishingCredentialsEnabled' of undefined"

after deployment. The isSitePublishingCredentialsEnabled was not found on my code. I never encountered this error before.

I tried repushing my code and rerunning the pipeline but still receives the same error. I did not change any configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/18172) that has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please Create New Service Connection, We faced same issue, after creation of new service connection it's solved.